# Mongo: db.collection.findOne() issues

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to implement the Like route. When a user is authenticated and want to like a post from another user(Scream), in MongoDb should create a document in "likes" collection with  these parameters: 
1.screamId == the Id of the post  
2.name == the user who liked the post.  
After that, the likeCount of that post is increased by one and then the post is saved in database.

I have issues with .find / .findOne methods, because i wanna check if a post is already liked by that user. 
I wanna to implement a condition, if that likeDoc already exists, it should return "Already liked..."

// With .find method, the likeCount is increasing(everything is cool), but the condition to check if likeDoc is already exists doesn't work and it creates everytime new doc with same screamId and name.

With .findOne method, i get this error: 
*(node:12240) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null
at C:\Users\Marius\Desktop\my-app\back-end\routes\likes.js:20:11*

Can you please help with some tips how to repair this error?

```
const router = express.Router();
const auth = require("../middleware/auth");

const { Scream } = require("../models/scream");
const { Like } = require("../models/like");

router.get("/:id", auth, async (req, res) => {
  const scream = await Scream.findById(req.params.id);
  if (!scream)
    return res
      .status(404)
      .send("The scream with the given ID was not found...");

  doc = await Like.findOne({
    screamId: req.params.id,
    name: req.user.name,
  });

  if (doc.name === req.user.name)
    return res.status(400).send("The scream is already liked");

  doc = new Like({
    screamId: req.params.id,
    name: req.user.name,
  });

  scream.likeCount++;
  await scream.save();

  await doc.save();
  res.send(doc);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: are you sure you are getting `req.user` ? if its null  `req.user.name` will give that error

Comment: You need to check if the `doc` exist before you access its properties, use `doc && doc.name === req.user.name` instead of just `doc.name === req.user.name`, actually, you can use just `if (doc) {..}`

Comment: @Titus was right, i need to check first if the doc exists. Thank you guys, a lot!

Answer (score 0):

req.user.name is not a valid param.
check where you are passing name param in req. ideally, it should be req.body.name or req.params.name.

Comment: it may be a valid property if OP has middleware which is adding it.

Comment: req.user is a valid param, from auth middleware(i decode the token and then i get req.user)